# ¿Como asigno valores de un array en PHP a un javascript

Tags: javascript, php, array

buen dia, tengo una duda que me esta volando la cabeza, estoy haciendo una pagina web que muestra un slider dinamico de imagenes, el usuario puede modificar, eliminar o agregar imagenes, utilizo: PHP, MySQL y javascript.
tengo un codigo donde hago la consulta de las imagenes

```
<?php
                $a = 0;
                include("conexion.php");

                $query = "SELECT * FROM tabla_imagen";
                $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
                while($row = $resultado ->fetch_assoc()){
                $pic [$a]=($row['Imagen']); 
                ++$a;
                }
            ?>
```

El array se esta guardando en $pic, mi codigo en javascript es:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            var imagenes = [];
            var flag=0;
            var tiempo = 5000;

            for (flag = 0; flag < <?php echo count($pic)?>; flag++) {
                imagenes[flag] = 'data:image/jpg;base64, <?php echo base64_encode($pic[flag]); ?>';
            }

            var indiceImagenes = 0;

            function cambiarImagenes(){

                document.slider.src = imagenes[indiceImagenes];
                if (indiceImagenes < <?php echo count($pic)-1;?>) {

                    indiceImagenes++;
                }else{
                    indiceImagenes = 0;
                }
            }
            setInterval(cambiarImagenes, tiempo)
        });
    </script>
```

donde especificamente el codigo:

```
for (flag = 0; flag < <?php echo count($pic)?>; flag++) {
                imagenes[flag] = 'data:image/jpg;base64, <?php echo base64_encode($pic[flag]); ?>';
            }
```

me arroja error en la variable "flag", estoy consiente que no se puede combinar javascript con php de esa forma, pero, ¿alguien tiene alguna idea de como se puede hacer?, de ante mano gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente el error que arroja? Sea como sea, deberías ir pensando en separar contextos, evitando mezclar código del servidor (PHP) con código del cliente (Javascript). Hoy día, la comunicación entre cliente y servidor se hace por medio de Ajax, o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript.

Comment: el error que me manda es el siguiente: **<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant &quot;flag&quot; in C:\xampp\htdocs...**

Comment: Es como te dije en mi anterior comentario, lo que debes hacer es obtener la información de `$pic` en el servidor (PHP) y mandarla al cliente (Javascript), luego en el cliente recorres el array y verificas lo que tengas que verificar (los `if` y demás cosas). Esa comunicación entre cliente y servidor debes hacerla por medio de Ajax o de la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. Te recomiendo que leas sobre el tema y luego que intentes un código basado en una de esas dos posibilidades y si tienes problemas podremos ayudarte. Ponte por norma NO meter nunca código PHP en un contexto Javascript.

Comment: cual es el objetivo de flag como variable, contener que???

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 El objetivo de la variable `flag` es ser un indice para el array `$pic`

Comment: no deberías de hacer algo como flag = count(element) y lo usas como el valor máximo en tu foreach???

Comment: puedes compartir el html final de las imagenes por favor???

Comment: quisiera aportarte una alternativa 100% en javascript que evitaria que hagas peticiones innecesarias al servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP no se ejecuta en el navegador, PHP crea la pagina o formatea la página en el servidor y la manda al navegador dónde JavaScript se encarga. En otra palabra para PHP JavaScript es solo otra etiqueta HTML y no lo ejecuta por lo que la variable `Flag` para PHP no existe y por eso te manda ese error. Aconsejo que no mezcles PHP con JavaScript.

Aqui te dejo lo equivalente a lo que intentas hacer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var imagenes = [
            <?php
                for ($pic as $p){
                    echo "'data:image/jpg;base64, ".base64_encode($p)."',";
                }
                echo "undefined";
            ?>
        ];
        var tiempo = 5000;
        var indiceImagenes = 0;

        function cambiarImagenes(){

            document.slider.src = imagenes[indiceImagenes];
            if (indiceImagenes < imagenes.length-1) {

                indiceImagenes++;
            }else{
                indiceImagenes = 0;
            }
        }
        setInterval(cambiarImagenes, tiempo)
    });
</script>
```

Nota: El ultimo elemento es `undefined` Por lo que aconsejo eliminarlo o ignorarlo.

Recomiendo que uses [AJAX con JQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)(La pagina esta en ingles, pero es interesante la lectura de ella):

**get_image.php**

```
<?php 
    include("conexion.php");
    $pic=array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tabla_imagen";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
    while($row = $resultado ->fetch_assoc()){
        $pic []=$row['Imagen'];/*Podemos omitir el índice y cada nuevo elemento PHP lo agregara al final.*/
    }
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");/*Determinamos que enviaremos un array json por medio de la petición HTTP*/
    echo json_encode($json);/*Enviamos el array JSON.*/
?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script src=”https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js”>
    /*La mayoría de la veces esto se hace con JQuery porque provee mas compatibilidad con los navegadores al momento de usar AJAX y es más fácil.*/
</script><!--Usamos AJAX para recibir los datos-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var imagenes = [];//Despues lo llenaremos.
        var tiempo = 5000;
        var indiceImagenes = 0;
        $.ajax({
            "type":"POST",
            "url":"get_image.php"
            "data":{"datos":"null"},/*Como no vamos a pedir nada no estoy seguro pero se puede dejar vacio.*/
        }).done(function(arr){//En caso de exito esta función se llama, de lo contrario se llamará la que sigue: fail(
            imagenes=arr;
        }).fail(function(){
            alert("Error no se pudieron obtener los datos.");
        });
        
        function cambiarImagenes(){
            document.slider.src = imagenes[indiceImagenes];
            if (indiceImagenes < imagenes.length-1) {
                indiceImagenes++;
            }else{
                indiceImagenes = 0;
            }
        }
        setInterval(cambiarImagenes, tiempo)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Excelente me funciono para este ejemplo sencillo! De igual forma buscaré más adelante no combinar php y JavaScript, gracias!

Comment: Si. Lo que hice fue combinar php y js, pero como ya sabes no debí hacerlo( Eso es lo que dice el estándar de php ).

Comment: esto sigue mesclando dos tecnología distintas, no debe de ser....

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Si.. lo se, hubiera contestado usando AJAX separando los dos lenguajes(Manteniendo una comunicación entre el servidor y JavaScript), pero no me especializo en programación de lado del servidor y no se como hacerlo, me especializo mas en el lado de cliente, Esperaba que otro pusiera una respuesta con esto.

Comment: me parece que esto se puede resolver 100% con javascript... si en el html tienes todos los elementos...